# Does "leave" mean "by using" in some situations? If yes, what are they?

Tags: meaning

The tutorial is [saying](https://youtu.be/3P49hWpNIzA?t=202)

> once the studs are laid out we're going to put them in place, **leave** their
>   hammer or nail gun.

I guess **leave** means using here. That guy indeed use nail gun a few seconds later.

So, what are the situations where "leave" mean "by using"?

Comment: I'm not convinced it says **leave**.  I can't be certain, because he has a fairly strong accent with which I'm not familiar, and the audio quality isn't great at my end, but I think he says either "**we'll need** a hammer or nail gun" or "**with either** a hammer or nail gun".

Comment: It's "...in place. With either a hammer or nail gun."

Comment: @stevekeiretsu Thank you so much. Would you please move your comments to answer? 
I'll accept it.

Comment: @mkennedy is correct, the man says "with either a hammer or nail gun".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be a small consensus that the man actually says "**with either** a hammer or nail gun", not "leave".

As to the question as originally asked, based on the wording originally (mis)heard, the short answer is that leave does not mean "by using".